# Building live network graphics

Tags: network-monitoring, graphics, networking

I'm interested in how OVH made [these graphics](http://weathermap.ovh.net). Can somebody explain in depth how it all works technically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a various network weathermap software out there, it looks like it might use this one: http://netmon.grnet.gr/weathermap/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.network-weathermap.com/

I use a NagVis 1.5 weathermap with Nagios at my site.
Cacti+weathermap is a good option too.

Answer (score 0):

They have a bunch of lines, they get information about how busy they are, they graph them - that's it really.